# Mouse coordinates in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have a map for my game, I have a script that on a click displays an alert of the mouse coordinates on the map.

The map scale is 1 map unit to 2.5 pixels and the map starts at -600, 600 and goes down to 600, 1700. Thus I can't simply throw out the pixels of the mouse.

I got it working (and was pretty happy about it) but alas IE (6) has issues. I have narrowed it down to IE not correctly getting the scroll parameters.

Here is the relevant code that is glitching but the full code is located at http://woarl.com/map/ieMap.html

```
tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: How to make it so that IE doesn't go wrong :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
tempX = event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft);
tempY = event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop);
```

Checked your page, and the DOCTYPE is putting IE in standards mode, so the `scrollXXX` properties you want are actually in `document.documentElement`, not `document.body`.

Comment: Dude, you just fixed a bug I've spent the last couple of days tracking down! Thanks :-D

Answer (score 2):

Mouse coordinate locations are horrible, due to the specs not noting whether they ought to be relative to the document or the viewpane, amongst other things.  There's a good description of the problem, as well as an example of script that should work across all browsers, at the bottom of http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html.

In particular it looks like you need to add `document.documentElement.scroll(Left|Top)` as well as the event and document.body parameters.